# Building and testing HTTP-Proxy-0.304

Tags: perl, makefile, cpan, cpanm

I use `sudo cpanm` to test and install Perl dependencies.

I am stuck on the line

```
building and testing HTTP-Proxy-0.304
```

but I cannot continue the compilation.

Of course I made a Perl `Makefile.pl` to see the dependencies that are missing. I also tried a `cpan install HTTP-Proxy` and I also have a `cpanm` error

> Failed test '302 => 302 Server

I also commented out the proxy line in the `Makefile.pl` the `cpanm` turn on but the compilation `make` and `make test` crashes.

Where does this message blocking on the proxy come from and how can I install this dependency via `cpanm` or `cpan`?

In both cases use of `sudo cpanm` and `cpan install ...` I get a timeout or it gets stuck on this step that's all. He does not go further

Comment: "I can not continue then." is not an adequate description of the problem.

Comment: *"Of course I made a Perl `Makefile.pl` to see the dependencies"* You shouldn't have to do that; the correct `Makefile.PL` is packaged with the distribution of the module. *"Where does this message blocking on the proxy come from"* what message blocking?

Comment: *"I also tried a `cpan install HTTP-Proxy`"* `cpan` and `cpanm` expect the name of the *module*, not the name of the distribution.

Comment: I'm sorry: I meant to explain that the module in the `HTTP-Proxy` distribution is `HTTP::Proxy`, so `cpan HTTP::Proxy` should work.

Comment: The full error message is `Failed test '302 => 302 Server closed connection without sending any data back'` which is much more helpful. Take a look at [Bug #123067 for HTTP-Proxy: t/90httpstatus.t started to fail](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=123067). And please don't cut error messages short like that when you're asking for help.

Comment: Copy and paste your complete build log using `cpan`

Answer (score 1):

the problem referenced on the website like rt.cpan.org and others show that the HTTP service: Proxy blocks the continuation of the programs. The solution I found is to run the command

> sudo sudo cpanm . -v --notest then a sudo cpanm . -v

and with this everything works. We avoid to pass in the tests and then we launch the standard command. It's ok so